# sql recursive within a range

Tags: t-sql, recursive-query

I have a sql query to form a parent/child structure to a tree-like view, the outcome is like this:

lvl1a

lvl1a/lvl2a

lvl1a/lvl2b

lvl1b/lvl2a/lvl3a

lvl1c

lvl1d/lvl2a/lvl3a/lvl4a

...

the query itself doesn't have a limited range, for instance, if i only want to get this tree-like view for the first and second level
can someone modify the sql query to add such function? tks

```
;with cte as
     (
     select 
         labelID, 
         Title, 
         ParentLevel, 
         cast(Title as varchar(max)) as [treePath]
         from TestTable
         where ParentLevel = 0
         union all
             select
                 t.labelID,
                 t.Title,
                 t.ParentLevel,
                 [treePath] + '/' + cast(t.Title as varchar(255))
             from
                 cte
             join TestTablet on cte.labelID = t.ParentLevel
         )

     select  
         labelID,
         Title,
         ParentLevel,
         [treePath]
     from cte 
     order by treePath
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- All we did here was add lvl 0 for the first part of the union in the CTE
- then increment it by 1 each time the recursion occurs (after the union all)
- then add a where  clause to the select to eliminate levels beyond 2.

Though I find it odd this works since t isn't aliased in your code...
.

```
;with cte as
     (
     select 
         labelID, 
         Title, 
         ParentLevel, 
         cast(Title as varchar(max)) as [treePath],
         0 as lvl
         from TestTable
         where ParentLevel = 0
         union all
             select
                 t.labelID,
                 t.Title,
                 t.ParentLevel,
                 [treePath] + '/' + cast(t.Title as varchar(255)),
                 cte.lvl+1 as lvl
             from
                 cte
             join TestTablet t on cte.labelID = t.ParentLevel
         )

     select  
         labelID,
         Title,
         ParentLevel,
         [treePath]
     from cte 
     where lvl <=2
     order by treePath
```

Comment: nice and quick, tks for the reply ^_^

Comment: not to sure about the alias thing, is that something I need to be concerned? using mssql 2008 and the query executed well (although there's a comma missing before the cte.lvl )

Comment: For maintenance and readability, yes I would be concerned.  I added `testtablet t` in the 2nd part of the union I added the t... didn't see that in your original query.